# datomic: transact function not really writing to database

Tags: clojure, datomic

I'm running the dev db in datomic-free

However, I thought that it would write something to the database but when I do a pull, it's not there. this is my peer.clj

```
(ns dank.peer
  (:require [datomic.api :as d :refer (q)]
            [clojure.pprint :as pp]))

; Name the database as a uri
(def uri "datomic:mem://dank")

; Read the schema and seed data as strings
(def schema-tx (read-string (slurp "resources/dank/schema.edn")))
(def data-tx (read-string (slurp "resources/dank/seed-data.edn")))

; Initialize the db with above vars
(defn init-db
  []
  (when (d/create-database uri)
    (let
      [conn (d/connect uri)]
      @(d/transact conn schema-tx)
      @(d/transact conn data-tx))))

(init-db)

(def conn (d/connect uri))
(def db (d/db conn))

(defn create
  "Creates a new note"
  [notes]
    @(d/transact
      conn
      [{:db/id #db/id[:db.part/user]
        :item/author "default"
        :item/notes notes}]))

(defn get-notes
  [author]
    (d/pull-many db '[*]
      (flatten (into []
       (q '[:find ?e
            :in $ ?author
           :where
           [?e :item/author ?author]]
          db
          author
         )))))
```

`(create "some note")` ----> shows the whole transaction data structure with before and after.

`(get-notes "default")` ---> [] it is empty!

Am I missing something here?

Comment: What's `db` in your `get-notes` function? It should be something like `(d/db conn)`. Also, you can avoid the flatten,into, pulll-many and just do this in your query: `:find [(pull ?e [*]) ...]`

Comment: @Andre I edited the question to include those. where did you find that? I looked at the docs and came across pull-many and after wrestling with it was able to convert hashset into a vector and flatten it...

Comment: Use `(d/db conn)` instead of `db` in your `get-notes`. I don't currently have the time for giving a proper, long answer. But this will get you going again for now.

Comment: but isn't it already defined above (def db (d/db conn))  which is the same thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

mavbozo is correct in his response that when you call your `get-notes` function you are using a value of the database from before you transacted your new note.

If you were to call `(def db (d/db conn))` again prior to `get-notes` you will see the new data in the database.

However, it's generally preferred to avoid dealing with connections or databases as global variables, as it prevents function behaviors from being determined strictly from their parameters. As you noticed, the behavior of `get-notes` depends on the state of the `db` variable in your global state. As a rule of thumb, it's better to pass a database value to functions that query or pull from the database and pass a connection to functions that transact against a database or monitor the state of a database over time (see http://docs.datomic.com/best-practices.html#consistent-db-value-for-unit-of-work for more discussion of individual values of a Datomic database).

In this case, your `get-notes` function could be something like:

```
(defn get-notes
  [db author]
    (d/q '[:find (pull ?e [*])  
           :in $ ?author
           :where
           [?e :item/author ?author]]
          db
          author))
```

Which you can then invoke via:

```
(get-notes (d/db conn) "default")
```

To query the most current version of the database. This approach also has the advantage that you can call `get-notes` with any database value (i.e. the most recent, one from a given time in the past, or a history db).

Similarly, I would recommend changing your `create` function to take a connection instead of using the globally defined conn.

As far as managing your connection, again it is best to avoid using a global variable whenever possible. Some preferred options might be to put the connection into an application state map or an atom that is passed throughout your program as appropriate. Another good option that is used frequently is to leverage Stuart Sierra's component library (https://github.com/stuartsierra/component) to manage the lifecycle of the connection.

Comment: this is a much better and comprehensive answer.

Comment: and another question, conn just represents a connection to the database so it doesn't have any multiple state and is constant? And what about `init-db` do I need to seed the database every time and is everything lost when the repl disconnects? and anyway to speed up the startup time it takes 20+ seconds for the script to run via `lein exec -p src/dank/peer.clj`

Answer (score 4):

t0, t1, t2 denote increasing time t where t0 precedes t1, t1 precedes t2

`(d/db conn)` returns current snapshot of datomic database when the call is made.

let's say in t0 you called (def db (d/db conn)). At time t0 the notes are empty. the db here is a snapshot of db time t0.

then you create something during time t1 using (create "some note"). At time t1, the notes at least contain 1 note.

then during time t2 you call (get-notes "default"). At time t2, the notes at least contain 1 note.

the problem is, the `db` inside `get-notes` still refers to database snapshot during time `t0` that is the `db` you retrieve using `(def db (d/db conn))` at `t0`. At time `t0`, there are still no notes. That's why `get-notes` return empty.

when you query a datomic database, you must specify which db you want to query: the db as of now, yesterday db, db from 1 hour ago, etc. Of course, it's quite easy to get db as of now, just call `(d/db conn)`.

I find it useful to make db explicit for query functions such as changing your `get-notes` function declaration parameter to `(defn get-notes [db author] ....)`.

Comment: ohhhh! is there any more documentation on this seems like I missed this very important concept. So basically do `(get-notes db author)` and pass in a new `(def db d/db conn)` ? or just use `(d/db conn)` inside `get-notes`

Comment: @user299709 I got that important concept from following this official tutorial http://docs.datomic.com/tutorial.html

Comment: @user299709 since datomic query only requires db and not connection, I prefer passing only db to get-notes function. You can retrieve the db outside get-notes function. The pattern is described in this article http://www.rkn.io/2014/02/10/datomic-antipatterns-connnnn/